# lineSpacingExtra doesn't work on a TextView

Tags: android

I have a `TextView` whit custom `TextAppearance` that changes space between lines:

```
<style name="CustomAppearance">
    <item name="android:lineSpacingExtra">30sp</item>
</style>

<TextView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum..."
  android:textAppearance="@style/CustomAppearance" />
```

The problem is that `lineSpacingExtra` value is ignored when the app launches. (Though it works if I use `CustomAppearance` through `style` instead of `textAppearance` attribute)

Comment: People downvoting and flagging this: Please read https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/ and  https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer, answering your own question is not only allowed, it is *encouraged*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't work because `lineSpacingExtra` isn't supported inside [TextAppearance](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable#TextAppearance):

> Some common TextView attributes not included are lineHeight[Multiplier|Extra], lines, breakStrategy & hyphenationFrequency. TextAppearance works at the character level, not paragraph so attributes affecting the whole layout are not supported. [TextView styling by Nick Butcher](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/whats-your-text-s-appearance-f3a1729192d)

The solution for me was to use [MaterialTextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/textview/MaterialTextView) along with `lineHeight` attribute:

```
<com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum..."
          android:textAppearance="@style/CustomAppearance" />

<style name="CustomAppearance">
        <item name="lineHeight">30sp</item>
</style>
```